# Are aircraft accidents more frequent in specific countries?

Tags: safety, accident-statistics

In the past months I heard about several aircraft accidents that happened to occur in Russia, Indonesia, Malaysia... and I was wondering if some countries are actually more connected to accidents than other.

Is there some statistics on this topic? and if so, do they confirm this alleged over-representation, and do we know the reasons behind?

Comment: The Russians make fake airports and then put big rocks on the runways.

Comment: Because you are only watching very specific TV news, apparently ... have a look here: http://avherald.com/h?list=&opt=7680

Comment: thanks @J.Hougaard you are right, Probably it is because of spesific media companies.

Comment: @TylerDurden that was good buddy :)

Comment: Certainly some countries (and some aircraft operators within the same countries) don't have the same aviation safety standards as others, but aircraft crashes are hardly unique to Russia, Indonesia, and Malaysia. The most recent airliner crash to make international news was flying from France to Egypt, for example.

Comment: I don't agree that this is off topic; discussing aviation safety is certainly on topic. But it would be a much better question if it were more along the lines of [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29539/16960), looking for specific evidence.

Comment: @fooot And yet almost no one is voting up my question as a good one :(

Answer (score 4):

Crashes, meaning accidents with significant number of fatalities, are so rare, even in places with least attention to safety, that it is not possible to conclude the risk is higher in some countries with statistics.

And if you wanted to judge from the number of *incidents*, that is including events that were dangerous, but ended well, you would be stopped by the fact that quality of incident reporting varies wildly. In [this interview](http://avherald.com/h?article=45483425) Simon Hradecky, the editor of [The Aviation Herald](http://avherald.com/), explains that Canadian TSB reports many, many incidents, but that is is not because the safety would be poor in Canada – quite to the contrary – but because they have particularly good system of reporting them. So many incident reports can actually be taken as a sign of good safety in that country, but you can't make any statistics from that.

Regarding the countries you mention:

- Indonesia is widely believed to have poor safety. The [EU Air Safety List](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/safety/air-ban/index_en.htm) says:

  > All air carriers certified by
  >   the authorities with
  >   responsibility for regulatory
  >   oversight of Indonesia, with
  >   the exception of Garuda
  >   Indonesia, Airfast Indonesia,
  >   Ekspres Transportasi
  >   Antarbenua, Indonesia Air
  >   Asia, Citilink, Lion Air and
  >   Batik Air, including …

  clearly indicating that EASA does not believe the aviation authority of Indonesia oversees operators registered under them sufficiently.

  Together with high incidence of severe weather and a lot of mountainous terrain this creates environment where the risk *might* be elevated. As mentioned above, even there accidents are not that common to allow firm statistical conclusion.

  The excepted airlines however proved to EASA that they have a safety management system in place and that it works according to industry best practice. With them, the risk probably isn't significantly higher than with any other decent airline.
- Malaysia and Russia: I have not noticed any specific concerns about safety in those two countries. If you seem to have noticed accidents in those two countries in particular, it is likely just bad luck.

Comment: I don't have anything to back it up at the moment but I feel like there's something to be said about Malaysia and Russia. Maybe not as bad as Indonesia, but still.

Comment: @fooot, well, something can be said about Malaysia and Russia: Russia committed act of terrorism against Malaysia two years ago. But regarding accidents, for Malaysia I can only think about the missing MH370, which, while widely known, is a unique case that does not allow making any general conclusions. And for Russia the last bigger problem was the triple thrust reversers problem on Tu-204 that ended with crash on the last occurrence in 2012. Since then I recall 2 more crashes in Russia, but neither was Russian aircraft or crew. Nothing systemic in either.

Comment: @JanHudec I don't know about Russia now, but if you read about things during the Soviet period, especially regarding the space and nuclear industries, it's pretty clear that there was really no safety culture there. From appearances that appears to have changed, though.

Comment: @TomMcW, in many areas, the safety culture is still pretty poor there, but it seems that the aviation authority does do its job. Which is not commonplace; Russian government is still highly infested with corruption in general.

Comment: @JanHudec Was Soviet aviation better than other industries? Their nuclear energy industry had an awful safety record. They took way too many risks and important technical jobs were given on the basis of politics rather than qualifications. Read a book by a US bone marrow specialist that went there to help after Chernobyl. He related that their doctors were **very** familiar with radiation burns, suggesting they were fairly common. Radiation illnesses are exceedingly rare everywhere else. I really hope they've improved on such an unforgiving technology as nuclear power

Comment: @TomMcW, I suspect it actually, at least to an extent, indeed was always better. Covering up radiation accidents was relatively easy, but covering up aircraft crashes would have been a problem, especially crashes of their aircraft abroad. And they did always care about their image. So they did care about aviation safety, at least on the international lines, more than in other places.

Comment: i really appreciated for your answer and upvoted as a total beginner, but still i am pretty sure about lack of aviation for post-soviet countries.(well please do not judge me, i have travelled 42 countries and maybe 40 different companies but if i live that vibration of turkish airlines, quatar airlanes...etc. on landing i never buy ticket again but vibration and risk is more to be like felt for aeroflot,azal[azerbaijan airlines]..etc soviet ones, is clear) I do not want to emphasize spesific airlines of course, but the way is going to goal is starting from here! do you have any stat?

Comment: @abidinberkay, other post-soviet countries are a different story: Kazakhstan and Kyrgyzstan are on the EU Air Safety list. As I explained, I don't think reliable statistics is possible.